# Can't start new fish session after incorrectly closing fish_config

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying out `fish` (the friendly interactive shell), and tried out the browser-based config with `fish_config`. I didn't close this correctly. I hit `ctrl-C` in my shell.

Now I see the error "The request received an error. Perhaps the server has shut down." (image below)

[image]

Before looking up how to properly close the session (close the tab, then hit `Enter`!), I tried opening a new terminal tab, but it just hung forever. So I freaked out and restarted my computer.

And get this! **It's still like that.** When I visit `localhost:8000` OR `localhost:8001`, I see the same fish error on either one. And opening a new shell is completely busted.

**How do I reset fish?** What's it doing, and how do I stop it? (I might have to use a different shell to do anything...)

#### Update

I opened Activity Monitor and quit `fish` (which also quit `fishd`). Now the browser sessions are no longer there, but I still can't open a prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset fish to its starting state, delete (or rename) `~/.config/fish`.